# как добавить пробел после ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

эта строка кода печатает массив но при печати они соединени как добавить пробел между ними

```
   <div *ngFor="let allTitles of navItem">
    <a (click)="allTitles.color='orange'" href="#">{{allTitles.title}}</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что Вам нужно.
Можете показать результат вывода и что передаете в navItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле контейнер не обязателен. Ну а в качестве "пробела" используйте стили

```
    <a *ngFor="let allTitles of navItem"
        style="margin-right: 5px" 
        (click)="allTitles.color='orange'" 
        href="#">
    {{allTitles.title}}
    </a>
```